# Why LLVM does not remember an integer range when the variable has been constrained by an if statement?

Tags: clang, llvm

There is a problem that has become quite popular these last days regarding the LLVM/GCC inability to optimize a trivial loop when the range is quite obvious.

Godbolt for all the examples below: https://godbolt.org/z/b3PzrsE5e

The code below will not optimize and the generated assembly will produce a loop.

```cpp
uint64_t sum1( uint64_t num ) {
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    for ( uint64_t j=0; j<=num; ++j ) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

produces

```
sum1(unsigned long):                               # @sum1(unsigned long)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpq    %rdi, %rax
        jbe     .LBB0_1
        retq
```

However if one adds a limiter to the range of the variable, like an AND mask, the loop is able to optimize. You can also easily make it optimize if you change the condition `j<=num` to `j<num+1`.

```cpp
uint64_t sum2( uint64_t num ) {
    num &= 0xFFFFFFFFULL;
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    for ( uint64_t j=0; j<=num; ++j ) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

produces

```
sum2(unsigned long):                               # @sum2(unsigned long)
        movl    %edi, %eax
        addq    $1, %rax
        retq
```

while curbing the range with an if statement does not have any effect

```cpp
uint64_t sum3( uint64_t num ) {
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    if ( num <= 0xFF ) {
        for ( uint64_t j=0; j<=num; ++j ) {
            sum += 1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Produces assembly code again with a loop.

```
sum3(unsigned long):                               # @sum3(unsigned long)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        cmpq    $255, %rdi
        ja      .LBB3_2
.LBB3_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpq    %rdi, %rax
        jbe     .LBB3_1
.LBB3_2:
        retq
```

For that sake, even `__builtin_assume( num < 0x100ULL )` has no effect on the result.

I have looked into the LLVM code and traced this to the failed statement at

```cpp
  // lib/Transforms/Scalar/IndVarSimplify.cpp:1430
  const SCEV *MaxExitCount = SE->getSymbolicMaxBackedgeTakenCount(L);
  if (isa<SCEVCouldNotCompute>(MaxExitCount)) {
    printf( "Could not compute\n");
    return false;
  }
...
```

which then ends up in

```cpp
//  lib/Analysis/ScalarEvolution.cpp:7253
  const SCEV *ScalarEvolution::getExitCount(const Loop *L,
                                          const BasicBlock *ExitingBlock,
                                          ExitCountKind Kind) {
  switch (Kind) {
  case Exact:
  case SymbolicMaximum:
    return getBackedgeTakenInfo(L).getExact(ExitingBlock, this);
  case ConstantMaximum:
    return getBackedgeTakenInfo(L).getConstantMax(ExitingBlock, this);
  };
  llvm_unreachable("Invalid ExitCountKind!");
}
```

What I don't understand is why the boundary cannot be inferred if the if statement makes it clear? Is this a feature that could be implemented? Am I in the right track?

Comment: Are you trying to ask why noone has written code to do this?

Comment: I dont think this affirmative is correct. The optimization is there, there is code. Just that it's not being triggered in some edge cases for some reason. I want to know why.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick there, and commented based on an assumption. I've seen similar behaviour, which was because an already long LLVM function missed one case. I assumed that yours was like that.